# Bounded functions and inclusion on the $L^{p} $ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $f \in L^p(X) $ be a bounded function, show that $\forall q \geq p, \; f \in L^q(X)$

I'm aware that this result holds for the case where $\mu(X)<\infty$ but I can't see how to prove this for when the measure of the whole space is not necessarily finite. I've tried using Holder's inequality but that didn't seem to help much.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is bounded there is some $K >0$ such that
$$
|f| \leq K.
$$
Hence
$$
\int |f|^q d\mu= \int |f|^p|f|^{q-p} d\mu \leq \int K^{q-p}|f|^p d\mu=K^{q-p} \int |f|^p d\mu.
$$
Since $f \in L_p$, $\int |f|^p d\mu$ is finite. Hence $\int |f|^q d\mu$ is finite and $f \in L_q$.

Comment: Why would you expect It to be true in general?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space Take a look at **embbedings** on the Properties of $L_p$ spaces section.

Comment: I meant for the counting measure on $N$, not generally...

Comment: Then the integral becomes the sum $\sum  |f(n)|^q$. Since the integral exists the sum converges. Hence you can suppose that $|f(n)|<1$ for $n \geq n_0$. Notice now that $|f(n)|^q<|f(n)|^p$ for $n \geq n_0$ and finish the proof

Comment: This is exercise 6L on bartle elements of integration and lebesgue measure book

Comment: thanks i'll try to do it,Can you add a link for this book?

Comment: Sorry I can not. But I believe you will be able to find If you search for It. ;)

Comment: so in your method, getting that $|f(n)|^q<1$ for every $n>n_0$ is enough to conclude that the its the sum $\sum |f(n)|^q $ converges thus $f\in L^q$?

Comment: Since the sum converges $|f(n)|^q \to 0$ hence $|f(n)| \to 0$. And if $|f(n)|<1$ you know that $|f(n)|^q \leq |f(n)|^p$ for all $q \geq p$.